# Angular ngOnInit executed when the component is not present on the DOM

Tags: angular

Quick question here,
I have this component that is a Modal Dialog, this is the HTML:

```
<div class="modal__backdrop">
  <div class="modal__container">
    <div class="modal__content" (modalclose)="closeDialog()">
      <ng-container *ngIf="visible === 'open'">
        <ng-content select="bo-wizard"></ng-content>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the view I'm using it I have this HTMl:

```
<bo-modal-dialog #modalDialog id="wizardModal">
    <bo-wizard></bo-wizard>
</bo-modal-dialog>
```

If you check on this image the Component inside the Modal Dialog doesn't exists on the DOM because of this condition `*ngIf="visible === 'open'"`:

[image: No object in the DOM]

But why the `ngOnInit` in the component `bo-wizard` inside the modal is being executed? How can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the condition on the parent div of Modal

```
<div class="modal__backdrop" *ngIf="visible === 'open'">
  <div class="modal__container">
    <div class="modal__content" (modalclose)="closeDialog()">
      <ng-container>
        <ng-content select="bo-wizard"></ng-content>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Shivansh Seth, That doesn't solve the problem, also the the important is that we need to hide the content not the actual Modal component.

Comment: since we are calling wizard component <bo-wizard></bo-wizard> in html , so angular will load it during onInit the only way if dont want to load it in onInit() then we have wrap this complete HTMl part in condition <bo-modal-dialog #modalDialog id="wizardModal">
    <bo-wizard></bo-wizard>
</bo-modal-dialog>

Comment: I'm not an Angular expert but I see this really wrong if I don't have a component reflected on the DOM that the Javascript code of that component will be ran

Comment: <bo-wizard></bo-wizard> this line of code will invoke your component & then HTMl & then apply the condition which we have in the HTMl template. we can verify this by using the console.log("wizard componenet called") in oninit of bo-wizard  component.

Comment: Yes I know it is being call, that's why I'm getting the wrong behavior, but your solution can not be implemented, basically because what we need to hide is the content of the modal, not the modal itself, so when you open the modal it will change the condition to the content.